# adjust the number of rows by rowspan

Tags: javascript, html, django

I want to send the django lists template to html, but I can not sure the number of values in the list.
When that have 2 values I can make a beautiful table, but when the values in the list change to less or more than 2, the size of table was not fit.
Is any method to let the rowspan changeable and fit the number of value

```
  <table class="table table-bordered" id = "table2">
  <thead class="thead-light">
           <tr>
              <th rowspan="2" style="width:5%" scope="rowgroup">title</th>
              {% for name, accuracy in item %}
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{name}}</th>
                <th scope="row">{{accuracy}}</th>  
              </tr>
              {% endfor %}
         
         </tr>
      </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
<th rowspan="{{ item|length }}" scope="rowgroup">title</th>
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems very helpful. However I want to get the first value's length, do you know how could I get that?

Comment: @Z.L for that you can use something like this: "len(item[0])" to get the length of first value.

Or you could just traverse all the items and get the maximum value using max() from all the items